# Error on Android app Azure dependency gradle build

Tags: android, azure, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am getting the following error on Android Studio 2.3.3 at Gradle sync.:

"`Error:Module 'com.microsoft.azure:azure-mobile-android:3.3.0' depends on one or more Android Libraries but is a jar."

The error disappears if I use

```
compile 'com.microsoft.azure:azure-mobile-android:3.1.0'
```

instead of

```
compile 'com.microsoft.azure:azure-mobile-android:3.3.0'
```

but i don't want to use an outdated version.

build.gradle file is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.my_software.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:11.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:11.0.1'
    //FOR microsoft Azure
    compile 'com.microsoft.azure:azure-mobile-android:3.3.0'
}
```

TEMPORARY SOLUTION:

```
compile('com.microsoft.azure:azure-mobile-android:3.3.0@aar'‌​)
```

(add @aar at the end).

Answer (score 1):

I reviewed the source code of [`azure-mobile-apps-android-client`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-android-client) on GitHub, and the difference of the `build.gradle` between [`3.1.0`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-android-client/blob/3.1.0/sdk/src/sdk/build.gradle) and [`3.3.0`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-android-client/blob/3.3.0/sdk/src/sdk/build.gradle) is that the version `3.3.0` required the dependency `com.android.support:customtabs:23.0.1`, but version `3.1.0` not. So you need to downgrade the `compileSdkVersion` & `targetSdkVersion` value from `25` to `23` to support the required Android library to resolve it, due to `com.android.support:customtabs:23.0.1` is belong to Android API 23.

Comment: Unfortunately downgrade to 23, rebuild and gradle sync didn't make any difference. I concluded that using `compile('com.microsoft.azure:azure-mobile-android:3.3.0@aar')` makes the error disappear. Hope they will fix it in the next version.