# How to fix Module depends on one or more Android Libraries but is a Jar when building Cordova App

Tags: android, asp.net, cordova, azure

I'm currently working on a Hybrid Mobile App using Cordova Tools for Visual Studio to render a Azure published Web App inside a mobile container. 
The Web App is developed using C# and ASP.Net Web Forms. It also uses Azure for the Database storage. Everything works fine when running the Cordova app in the browser.
The problem that I have is that when I try to build the app into an .apk file it throws this error:

**"Module 'com.microsoft.azure:azure-mobile-android:3.3.0' depends on one or more Android Libraries but is a Jar"**.

The only solutions that I came across were involving a **bower.gradle** file, but in my case the bower file it's a **.json** file so I can't use the "compile com..." inside the dependencies tag.

Any help will be really appreciated,
Thanks in advance!

Razvan T.

Comment: You can see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44755574/error-on-android-app-azure-dependency-gradle-build

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I already looked over it and it does not apply in my case as my bower file it's a .json and not a .gradle so the compile won't work. I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and Cordova Tools for Visual Studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved. The file where the dependencies were supposed to be added was **build.gradle**.

The solution was to open the project in Android Studio, make the changes and build the .apk successfully.

I hope this will help anyone that encounters the issue.

Thanks!!

Comment: Razvan,  this drives me crazy for the last 48 hours....Could you please be more specific. Are you saying you opened vs.net .sln file from android studio and made what changes?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, maybe you already solved your issue. In the build.gradle file, from what I can remember, I used this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44755574/error-on-android-app-azure-dependency-gradle-build to make the changes in the dependencies. Mainly different versions of libraries. In Android Studio i didn't open the sln, just navigate to your platforms/android folder and you will finde the .gradle file